# Update cart items in real-time using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When a user adds various items and quantities to the cart, I need to update the grand total in real-time.

I am using `setState()`, and I know it is usually `asynchronous`, so the changes are not reflected immediately. Is there a workaround to get the grand-total of the cart when the items and its quantities changes ?

My code so far:

```
handleChange(event){
        const itemPrice= [2.63, 33.44, 9.99]; // item-price in order Salmon, Apple, Papaya


        const val = event.target.value;
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: val,

        }, () => {
            if(this.state.item == 1) { // Salmon
             this.state({
                total : itemPrice[val -1]
             });
            } else if (this.state.item == 2) { // Apple
               this.state({
                total : itemPrice[val -1]
               });

            }
        });
        console.log(this.state);
    }
```

Comment: So far, you made the setState synchronous using the arrow operator, means the code inside that will execute only after the setState() finishes off. But am not still clear about the things inside the callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try like this.

```
handleChange(event) {
const itemDetails = [{
    name: 'salmon',
    price: 2.63
}, {
    name: 'apple',
    price: 33.44
}, {
    name: 'papaya',
    price: 9.99
}]; // item listing
const val = event.target.value;
let itemPrice = itemDetails.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.name === 'apple')
        return item.price;
})
this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: val,
    total: total + itemPrice //Add whatever prices you need
});
    console.log('total change: ' +this.state);
}
```

You may need to keep an array of items like this with it's price. In this way, you can update the total price on the change itself

Comment: This won’t ensure both happens together.

Comment: Yeah, but as soon as the item gets added to the state, the total will also change.

Comment: Is there anything else that I can use instead of setState for realtime calculations ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your state is having an array with size equal to dice of item prices (ideally should be a prop). And the also another state variable that is total amount.

In your handleChange you can update both quantity and total directly. You don’t have to update the total amount in the call back. This will ensure that the quantity array and total will be updated together.

Comment: The grand total depends on certain properties, Like delivery, wrapping etc. The price will reflect based on what the user selects. Therefore, I will need to have a seperate state to reflect this

Comment: In that case your grand total will change two folds once when you change the quantity and other when you change the wrapping and delivery, so two events triggered. Or like how most trip website like Expedia  pre compute those standard value for wrapping sand delivery and update in handle change itself not in callback.